# Want to multiply, not repeat variable

Tags: python

I want to input a command-line variable and then multiply it, but when I print the variable it repeats by the number I want to multiply it by.

eg:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
st_run_time_1 = sys.argv[1]*60

print ("Station 1 : %s" % st_run_time_1)
```

When I run the script I get the following:
    python3 test.py 2

```
Station 1 : 222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
```

Comment: You have run into one of the silliest features of Python: multiplying strings! Congratulations!

Comment: I wouldn't call it silly; it's a straightforward extension of using `+` for string concatenation. It's much nicer to write `"-"*60` than `"".join("-" for x in range(60))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sys.argv[x]` is string. Multiplying string by number casue that string repeated.

```
>>> '2' * 5         # str * int
'22222'

>>> int('2') * 5    # int * int
10
```

To get multiplied number, first convert `sys.argv[1]` to numeric object using [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) or [`float`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float), ....

```
import sys
st_run_time_1 = int(sys.argv[1]) * 60 # <---

print ("Station 1 : %s" % st_run_time_1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are multiplying a string with an integer, and that always means repetition. Python won't ever auto-coerce a string to an integer, and `sys.argv` is always a list of strings.

If you wanted integer arithmetic, convert the `sys.argv[1]` string to an integer first:

```
st_run_time_1 = int(sys.argv[1]) * 60
```

Comment: Will Python *ever* auto-coerce a string to an int?

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: nope. Updated to be less vague.